# How to use while loop properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, while-loop

I have a dataframe:

```
SIN1       SIN2      SIN3
4778       5633      4343
```

I have tried,

```
count_col = len(df1.columns)

check=1

while check<=count_col:
    check_str = str(check)
    check_for_column = "SIN"+check_str in df1
    name = "SIN"+check_str
    
    if check_for_column == True:
        df1[name] = df1[name].astype(str)
        df1['SIN1'] = df1['SIN1'] + ',' + df1[name]

    if check == count_col:
        break
    
    check += 1

df1[['SIN1']]
```

This shows `4778,4343,4778,4343.................`

When I tried,

```
check=1

while check<=count_col:
    check_str = str(check)
    check_for_column = "SIN"+check_str in df1
    name = "SIN"+check_str
    
   

    if check == count_col:
        break
    
    check += 1

if check_for_column == True:
     df1[name] = df1[name].astype(str)
     df1['SIN1'] = df1['SIN1'] + ',' + df1[name]

df1[['SIN1']]
```

This shows `4778,4343`

I want the result to be, `4778,5633,4343`

Please don't suggest a way to directly concatenate with ','.

I used while loop because there can be any no of SIN columns so.

How to properly use while loop in this case?

Comment: It is unclear as to what you are actually trying to accomplish. Can you elaborate on what the actual goal is.

Comment: The actual goal is display allcolumns like SIN1,SIN2,SIN3. Since the columns can be of any number so I am using while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` to join column values:

```
>>> df['SIN'] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x), axis=1)
```

```
>>> df

   SIN1  SIN2  SIN3             SIN
0  4778  5633  4343  4778,5633,4343
```

To select a subset of columns like `SINxx`, use `filter`:

```
df.filter(like='SIN')  # or df.filter(regex='SIN\d+')
```

Answer (score 0):

This code takes all columns with `SIN` in them, concatenates the values as a string, and assigns it to a new column `SIN`.

```py
sin_cols = [ ( 'SIN' in col ) for col in df.columns ]
sdf = df.loc[ :, sin_cols ]
df[ 'SIN' ] = sdf.apply( lambda x: ', '.join( x.values.astype( str ) ), axis = 1 )
```

`df` before

| id | T | SIN1 | SIN2 | Q | SIN3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 8 | 3 | 6 | 9 | 8 |
| 1 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 6 |

`df` after

| id | T | SIN1 | SIN2 | Q | SIN3 | SIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 8 | 3 | 6 | 9 | 8 | 3, 6, 8 |
| 1 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 6, 1, 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 6 | 2, 4, 6 |

Comment: In general for DataFrames, looping is a bad idea. Insead you should try to use the concept of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).